# Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x76c11b0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm relatively new to obj-c, so I must be missing something, but my program crash when an enemy collides with a wall. I've located where I'm removing the enemy from the loop, while in the loop, but for the life of me, i can't figure out how to fix it. 
My code is as follows:

(the error is "[allEnemies removeObject:enemyType1];")

//ALWAYS RUNNING
-(void) update:(ccTime)dt 
{

```
for (CCSprite *enemyType1 in allEnemies) { //for every attacking unit in allEnemies

    //Adjust the collison box for each enemey depending on the height of the enemy
    float a;
    float b;
    float yOne = (wall.contentSize.height-enemyType1.position.y);
    float yTwo = (wall.contentSize.height);
    float xTwo = 30;
    a = (xTwo*(yOne/yTwo)); // always < 1
    b = xTwo-a;             // always > 1


    //Create the altered collison box 
    CGRect enemyType1Rect = CGRectMake (
                enemyType1.position.x - (enemyType1.contentSize.width/2), 
                enemyType1.position.y - (enemyType1.contentSize.height/2), 
                enemyType1.contentSize.width+b, 
                enemyType1.contentSize.height
                                       );


    //If the enemey hits the wall, stop it, then add it to the attacking enemies array
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(enemyType1Rect, wall.boundingBox)) {
        [enemyType1 stopAllActions];
        [allEnemies removeObject:enemyType1];
        [attackingEnemies addObject:enemyType1];            
    }


}
//Wall Collison END
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, just as the error states, you mutated the array while it was being enumerated. The easiest fix is to do `for (CCSprite *enemyType1 in [[allEnemies copy] autorelease])` This way you're enumerating a copy of the array (this does NOT  copy the elements, just gives you another container to enumerate them in), and can still modify the mutable array.

You can not modify containers while enumerating them.

Comment: ok, so could you explain what exactly that does. Does [allEnemies copy] make a copy of the array, and will that remove it from the original "allEnemies" array. Also when you put "autorelease" in there, you dont need to have "[allEnemies removeObject:enemyType1];" right? Sorry if this sounds really dumb (i just got xcode 4 and non of this was bothering my in 3). 
edit:
So I changed that piece of code and now I get:

Couldn't register com.yourcompany.StromTheHouse with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.

Comment: Ok, xcode hates me. so I think I get "for (CCSprite *enemyType1 in [[allEnemies copy] autorelease])", and i don't get the bootstrap error, but now when i try to test on Device, i get a new error:

StormTheHouse[11129:707] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:wall.png in CCTextureCache
2011-12-10 11:02:05.888 StormTheHouse[11129:707] *** Assertion failure in -[HelloWorld addChild:], /Users/rauhul/Desktop/Invasion/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:385
2011-12-10 11:02:05.890 StormTheHouse[11129:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'

Comment: nvm those posts I figured out what was going on, i had referenced wall.png in my code but the images was WALL.png, Thx soooo much

Comment: You can also enumerate in reverse, in which case removing objects during iteration is legal.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D that is because doing [array reverseEnumerator] gives you another enumerator your'e dealing with, essentially a different array.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies within this line of code:  `[allEnemies removeObject:enemyType1];`
you are enumerating an array `allEnemies` and removing an object from the array in the same enumeration which is causing the issue. You should use a temp array for the looping while actually mutating(`removeObject:`) the other array.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete items from a `NSMutableArray` while iterating it.

There are several solutions to this:

- Iterate a copy of the array

or

- Use an index-based `for` loop instead of the `for each` syntax.

Not copying the array saves you an allocation and a few CPU cycles:

```
for (int i = updatedLocalityArray.count-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    NSString *test = updatedLocalityArray[i];
    if ([test isEqualToString:tableViewCell.textLabel.text])
    {
        [updatedLocalityArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@ *****", updatedLocalityArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this could be happen, when you are adding an object into NSMutableArray and reading record from that array. And these 2 tasks are happening in two different thread. Like one is happening in background thread and another one is happening on main thread. So careful about the threading as well.