# In my iPhone app,i am trying to implement a UISearchBar in Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

when search value from array am getting  <__NSArrayM:> was mutated while being enumerated. Am using this code.

```
NSInteger strlen=[searchText length];


for (NSString *pStr in pArrBusinessName ) {

    NSRange nameRange = [pStr rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption];

    if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {

        if (strlen == 1) {
            pArrFilteredTableData = pArrBusinessName;
        } else {

            if ([pStr isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                NSLog(@"NSNull isKindOfClass called!");
            }


            if (![pStr isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

                [pArrFilteredTableData addObject:pStr];

            }
        }

    } else {

        if ([pArrFilteredTableData count] == 0) {

        }

    }

    [pTblDetails reloadData];
}
```

Comment: So you apparently are looping through an array and changing it while inside of the loop. Instead create a new array to hold your search results and update that separately. You can head over to google and search for many examples of how to implement a UISearchBar in TableView. Plenty of examples on SO as well. Please search first before adding your question. I am fairly certain that the question will be marked as a duplicate. Don't be discouraged that is how things work on SO. Search first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collection <\_\_NSArrayM: 0x76c11b0> was mutated while being enumerated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458786/collection-nsarraym-0x76c11b0-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
pArrFilteredTableData = pArrBusinessName;
```

To this;

```
pArrFilteredTableData = [pArrBusinessName mutableCopy];
```

**make sure pArrFilteredTableData is a NSMutableArray if it wasn't already**

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you are doing modifications in the main array while searching the contents inside it. It would be good if you hold your search results in a separate mutable array rather than mutating the main array using which you created your list. Filter searched records from the main array and hold them in search array.

Comment: if (strlen == 1) {
            pArrFilteredTableData = pArrBusinessName;
        }

Comment: in above statement you are basically assigning the reference of pArrBusinessName to pArrFilteredTableData array and if further you have mutated the pArrFilteredTableData, it could effect the pArrBusinessName as pArrFilteredTableData basically holds the refrence of  pArrBusinessName.